# IOError on Scrapy Images Pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'm using Images Pipeline from Scrapy and for some images I'm getting this error:

```
[scrapy.pipelines.files] ERROR: File (unknown-error): Error processing file from <GET https://www.example.com/folder-name/image.jpg> referred in <None>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\files.py", line 401, in media_downloaded
    checksum = self.file_downloaded(response, request, info)
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\images.py", line 101, in file_downloaded
    return self.image_downloaded(response, request, info)
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\images.py", line 105, in image_downloaded
    for path, image, buf in self.get_images(response, request, info):
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\images.py", line 125, in get_images
    image, buf = self.convert_image(orig_image)
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\images.py", line 151, in convert_image
    image.save(buf, 'JPEG')
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1916, in save
    self.load()
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 254, in load
    raise_ioerror(err_code)
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 59, in raise_ioerror
    raise IOError(message + " when reading image file")
IOError: broken data stream when reading image file
```

The images are available on the server (without redirects) and I don't find any difference between the images that work and the ones which doesn't. Any idea of what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have any example of image where the processing failed?

Comment: The image link from your log lines is https://www.example.com/folder-name/image.jpg which does not look like a valid image to me. There is an assumption that the actual data fetched and passed to PIL shall be valid images. And if not, it's not surprising me that PIL fails.

Comment: Hi! The URL I'm passing is valid. I was doing some more tests and I think this is happening with big images like this one: https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/303836.jpg Any hint on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known [issue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1510). Upgrading Pillow dependency (`pip install Pillow --upgrade`) fixed it.